# Setting correct start and end time series for Savitzky-Golay in R

Tags: raster, r, time-series, smoothing

I am trying to smoothen my raster stack using Savitzky-Golay method. I am following the workaround from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37843942/smoothen-rasterstack-using-the-savitzky-golay-sgolayfilt-signal-in-r/37846229#37846229) but my problem is setting start and end of my time-series raster. My series of images were from October 2018 to March 2019 and can available [HERE](https://github.com/mpmarcaida/time-series-raster).

My code goes like this:

```
r <- stack("./KT_DS18_rice_ts.tif")
names(r) <- c("2018-10-08","2018-10-24","2018-11-09","2018-11-25",
                      "2018-12-11","2018-12-27","2019-01-09","2019-01-25",
                      "2019-02-10","2019-02-26","2019-03-14","2019-03-30")

fun <- function(x) {
  v=as.vector(x)
  z=na.spline(v)
  s1.ts2 = ts(z, start=1, end=nlayers(z), frequency=12)
  sgolayfilt(s1.ts2)  
}

fun(r)
```

I want to smooth the EVI curve of each pixel from the first layer (start) to the 12th layer (end). That code above gives me this error:

```
 Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable):unable to find an inherited method for function ‘nlayers’ for signature ‘"numeric"’
```

Comment: Please make your questions as self-contained as possible - how about creating a simple sample data set so we don't have to download? And say all the packages you use so we don't have to go hunting to discover you are using the `signal` package. Help us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note where the error is coming from and step through your code. Its not even getting to the Savitsky-Golay line.

```
> v = as.vector(r)
> z = na.spline(v)
> s1.ts2 = ts(z, start=1, end=nlayers(z), frequency=12)
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘nlayers’ for signature ‘"numeric"’
```

The error is clearly with **`nlayers`**. What are you calling it on?

```
> nlayers(z)
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘nlayers’ for signature ‘"numeric"’
```

`z` is the vector of values from your raster stack. It doesn't have "layers" so `nlayers` fails. Did you mean `nlayers(r)` to get the value 12?